# How can I destroy window __init__?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have my program with a class main and functions, the first one is the `__init__` with arguments `self` and `master`. That start with login window, so I want destroy that function `__init__` but I'm a noob in that and I can't :// I have tried `self.master.destroy()` and the things disappear but still one empty window showing. Can someone help me?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as ms
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os
import time
import pymysql

root = Tk()
root.title('Sistema de Senhas')

root.configure(background='white')

class main:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.username = StringVar()
        self.password = StringVar()

        self.logf = Frame(self.master,padx =10,pady = 10, bg='white')
        Label(self.logf,text = 'Utilizador: ',font = ('Corbel bold',13), bg= 'white',pady=5,padx=5).grid(sticky = W)
        Entry(self.logf,textvariable = self.username,bd = 2,font = ('Corbel bold',11)).grid(row=0,column=1)
        Label(self.logf,text = 'Palavra-passe: ',font = ('Corbel bold',13), bg= 'white',pady=5,padx=5).grid(sticky = W)
        Entry(self.logf,textvariable = self.password,bd = 2,font = ('Corbel bold',11),show = '*').grid(row=1,column=1)
        self.logf.pack()

        self.button = Button(self.master,text = 'Entrar',bd = 2 ,font = ('Corbel bold',12), relief='groove', bg= 'white',padx=5,pady=2,command=self.login)
        self.button.pack()

    def login(self):

        utilizador=self.username.get()
        password=self.password.get()

        self.connection = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", database="sistemasenhas")
        self.cur = self.connection.cursor()

        query="SELECT * FROM utilizadores WHERE nome=%s AND password=%s"
        data=self.cur.execute(query,(utilizador,password))

        if(len(self.cur.fetchall())>0):
            query="SELECT * FROM utilizadores WHERE nome=%s AND password=%s AND acesso=0"
            data=self.cur.execute(query,(utilizador,password))
            if(len(self.cur.fetchall())>0):
                master.destroy() # It's here
                self.janela()
            else:
                master.destroy() It's here
                self.admin()
        else:
            ms.showerror('Oops','Utilizador ou palavra-passe incorretos!')
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing with class main? Your example does not explain what it is you are doing. That said `destroy()` is the method you are looking for, it just depends on what you are doing to tell you how to use it properly.

Comment: I am confused by this question.

Comment: What do you mean by "destroy that function `__init__`"?

Comment: @Mike-SMT I just want make the login window disappears forever after the user make the login

Comment: @JosuéFreitas yes and `destroy()` is what you need for that. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: @ddg i just want make the login window disappears forever after the user make the login :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is somewhat confusing. Your example does not show the use of `destroy()` and you do not explain what you are attempting to do in class `main`. You don't want to destroy the "Method" `__init__` you probably want to close a window or the root window. My guess based on your question and example you are attempting to create a login window.

That said `destroy()` is the correct method.

Here is a simple example using your code that shows what you can do to close it.

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title('Login system')
root.configure(background='white')

class main:
    def __init__(self,master):
        Button(master, text='Exit', command=master.destroy).pack()

main(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Here is an example that is a bit cleaner and follow the OOP model.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Login system')
        self.configure(background='white')
        tk.Button(self, text='Exit', command=self.destroy).pack()

Main().mainloop()
```

Comment: i tried master.destroy() now give me a error: "name 'master' is not defined". can I show my code here for u help me?

Comment: @JosuéFreitas `master` is only avalible within the `__init__` method. You need to update your question with something testable for me to give a more complete answer.

Comment: @JosuéFreitas you cannot use master outside of the __init__ method. If you need to then you have to define it as a class attribute by using the `self.` prefix.So in your `login` method use `self.master` instead of `master`. Also you are calling `self.janela()` after master.destroy and that wont work. You probably need to take this to code review and post your full code. There is a lot that needs to be changed.